# glht() and lsmeans() can't find contrast in lmer() model

Tags: r

I have the following situation:

[image]

my fixed-effect model find a main effect of Relation_PenultimateLast in the group of participant called 'composers'. I want therefore to find what level of Relation_PenultimateLast differ statistically from the others.

```
f.e.model.composers = lmer(Score ~ Relation_PenultimateLast + (1|TrajectoryType) + (1|StimulusType) + (1|Relation_FirstLast) + (1|LastPosition), data=datasheet.complete.composers)
```

Summary(f.e.model.composers)

```
Random effects:
 Groups             Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 TrajectoryType     (Intercept) 0.005457 0.07387 
 LastPosition       (Intercept) 0.036705 0.19159 
 Relation_FirstLast (Intercept) 0.004298 0.06556 
 StimulusType       (Intercept) 0.019197 0.13855 
 Residual                       1.318116 1.14809 
Number of obs: 2200, groups:  
TrajectoryType, 25; LastPosition, 8; Relation_FirstLast, 4; StimulusType, 4

Fixed effects:
                         Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               2.90933    0.12476 14.84800  23.320 4.15e-13 ***
Relation_PenultimateLast  0.09987    0.02493 22.43100   4.006 0.000577 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I have to make a Tukey comparison of my lmer() model.
Now, I find two methods for the comparison among Relation_PenultimateLast levels (I have found them in here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237512/how-to-perform-post-hoc-test-on-lmer-model):

```
summary(glht(f.e.model.composers, linfct = mcp(Relation_PenultimateLast = "Tukey")), test = adjusted("holm"))
```

and

```
lsmeans(f.e.model.composers, list(pairwise ~ Relation_PenultimateLast), adjust = "holm")
```

These do not work.
The former reports:

```
Variable(s) ‘Relation_PenultimateLast’ of class ‘integer’ is/are not contained as a factor in ‘model’
```

The latter:

```
Relation_PenultimateLast   lsmean        SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
                      2.6 3.168989 0.1063552 8.5 2.926218  3.41176

Degrees-of-freedom method: satterthwaite 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

    $` of contrast`
     contrast  estimate SE df z.ratio p.value
     (nothing)   nonEst NA NA      NA      NA
```

Can somebody help me understand why I have this result?

Comment: can we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: PS sounds like you want to code `Relation_PenultimateLast` as a factor rather a 0/1 numeric variable?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to produce it part providing you with an excel file. Is there a way to transform a data.frame into a string that produces that data.frame?

Comment: I edit now the body of the test to describe my scenario

Comment: I would have also another question, though I think it's more correct for CrossValidate - why can I not use multiple lmer() to create multiple comparisons?

Comment: `?dput` .......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it's important to realize that the model you have fitted is inappropriate. It uses `Relation_PenultimateLast` as a numeric predictor; thus it fits a linear trend to its *values* 1, 2, 3, and 4, rather than separate estimates for each level of this as a factor. I also wonder, given the plot you show, why `Test` is *not* in the model; it looks like it should be (again as a factor, not a numeric predictor). I suggest that you get some statistical consulting help to check that you are using appropriate models in your research. Perhaps you could give a graduate student in statistics some grounding in practical applications -- a win-win proposition.

To model `Relation_PenultimateLast` as a factor, one way is to replace it in the model formula with `factor(Relation_PenultimateLast)`. That will work for `lsmeans()` but not `glht()`. A better way is probably to change it in the dataset:

```
datasheet.complete.composers = transform(datasheet.complete.composers,
    Relation_PenultimateLast = factor(Relation_PenultimateLast))
f.e.model.composers = lmer(...) ### (as before, assuming Test isn't needed)
```

(BTW, you must be a heck of a better typist than I am; I'd use shorter names, though I do applaud using informative ones.)

(Note: is `f.e.model.composers` supoposed to suggest a fixed-effects model? It isn't one; it is a mixed model. Again, a consultant...)

The **lsmeans** package is destined to be deprecated, so I suggest you use its continuation, the **emmeans** package:

```
library(emmeans)
emmeans(f.e.model.composers, pairwise ~ Relation_PenultimateLast)
```

I suggest using the default `"tukey"` adjustment rather than Holm for this application.

If indeed `Test` should be in the model, then it looks like you need to include the interaction; so it'd go something like this:

```
model.composers = lmer(Score ~ Relation_PenultimateLast * factor(Test) + ...)

### A plot like the one shown, but based on the model predictions:
emmip(model.composers, Relation_PenultimateLast ~ Test) 

### Estimates and comparisons of Relation_PenultimateLast for each Test:
emmeans(model.composers, pairwise ~ Relation_PenultimateLast | Test)
```

Comment: Amazing @rvl! You make me notice that I have name a mixed-effect as a fixed-effect. Sorry. I was suggested to use a mixed-effect, but the neuroscientist that was helping me in the beginning suddenly let me down because of his viva. I contacted another student and he said to me that he knew about qualitative statistics and not about quantitative statistics! So, please, teach me more! I have followed a course on statistics for psychology, but from theory to applied applications I miss experience

Comment: About the Test factor, in the specific moment I was interested to see only if there was a main effect, and following this concern (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/322608/different-results-for-between-within-groups-and-within-group-regression-analyses?noredirect=1#comment612853_322608) I was answered from a person from the mainling-list 'r-sig-mixed-effects' that when you create an interaction 'you're changing the amount of pooling going on, which affects shrinkage and the bias-variance / over- vs. underfitting tradeoff.'

Comment: 'When you fit a model to a subset, it will generally be better at describing that subset but often worse at describing the full set / other sets. In other words, your subset model better describes the subset because it doesn't have to spend "resources" describing the other data, but of course this also means that it will tend to not describe the other data as well - it's better at the small details but worse at the big picture.' So I was thinking that focusing my model on the main-effect was better for that parameter. Should I always include the interaction?

Comment: But now that you make me think, this speaks of subsets, not of factors, actually.

Comment: Problem: I have tried to use factor(), but it does not consider Relation_PenultimateLast=1. Only =2, =3, =4 (btw, this automatically runs a pairwise comparison, I see?)

Comment: It only runs half the pairwise comparisons (each compared wth level 1). If you do the emmeans step, you’ll see them all and observe that level 1 is not ignored.

Comment: I have a problem. Using factor(R_PL)*factor(Test), I have no space to visualise the whole result, and I only see results of Estimate, Std.Error and t value. Then I have a warning about rescaling, and then it returns

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by “no space...”, but this sounds like an issue in `lmer()`.  I still think it’d help f you find an actual statistics person (not a qualitative one, whatever that means) to help. I can’t teach statistics online.

Comment: Dear @rvl, sorry to disturb. I have used emmeans extensively, but through emmeans I can only see the pairwise comparison. What should I use to visualize the p_value of an interaction of two main fixed effects? Something like: "factor1*factor2 ... estimate .... p_value"

Comment: The p-value (singular "the") for an interaction would be obtained using something like `car::Anova(model, type = "2")` -- not using `emmeans()`. There is such a thing as interaction contrasts (plural) but there is no unique set of them and you have to understand what you're talking about. For more details, see `vignette("interactions", "emmeans")`.